# filter default query to show just selected level of child pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I'm working on a site that has a fairly large page structure a few levels deep - in some sections there are a lot of pages.

So I want to have functionality
if user choose on select box level 1 then only pages in level 1 will show in below list of pages.
if he choose level 2 then only level 2 pages,
same go to level 3 level 4 level 5 level 6.

it's working for top level parent pages when I set **query_vars['post_parent'] = 0;** and I want to have same functionality to show list of level 1 child page,level 2 child pages and so on...

I am stuck on it. please I will be great full if anyone can help me for it. Thanks
see screenshot link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKpy6.png

```
function level_page_admin_posts_filter( $query ) {
  global $pagenow;
  if ( is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && !empty($_GET['lavel_pages'])) {
      $level = $_GET['lavel_pages'];
      if($level == 'parent'){
        $query->query_vars['post_parent'] = 0;
      }else 
      if($level == 1){

      }else
      if($level == 2){

      }
  }
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'level_page_admin_posts_filter' );

function admin_page_filter_level_pages() {
  global $wpdb;
  if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'page') {
  
  $select = '
    <select name="lavel_pages">
      <option value="parent">Parent Pages</option>
      <option value="1">Level 1</option>
      <option value="2">Level 2</option>
      <option value="3">Level 3</option>
      <option value="4">Level 4</option>
      ';
  
  $select .= ' </select>';
  echo $select;
} else {
  return;
}
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'admin_page_filter_level_pages' );
```

Comment: Your title is about using `WP_Query` but you are not using it in the code you have shown us?

Comment: Sorry. i did updated title now. Thanks for coming. Do you understand what i am looking for ? I want to get list of 1 level child pages or 2 level child pages based on select box value. can you help me for it ? Thanks

Comment: I understand your question, but I only use WP_Query to query the WP database so I am unable to help with trying to query the WP database directly.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just want functionality to filter child pages based page level. i.e if level one selected from drop down list. need to show all pages which are child of top level parent page, if level 2 selected. need to show all pages which are grand child of top level page.
I don't focus what code i will use. if you can help using wp_query also it will great for me. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to do all in one single `WP_Query` because you get the child pages by specifying the parent... you would probably need to do it in 2 steps: first get all the level 0 parent pages and then use this list to get the child pages that have those parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if we get all the pages and work out what level each page is on and then filter the query using "post__in". Try the following:

```
//recursive function to get page level, function returns when parent page is zero
function level_page_admin_get_level($parentIds, $pageId, $level)
{
  $parentId = $parentIds[$pageId];
  if($parentId>0)
  {
    $level++;
    return level_page_admin_get_level($parentIds, $parentId, $level);
  }
  return $level;
}

function level_page_admin_posts_filter($query)
{
  global $pagenow;
  if(is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && !empty($_GET['lavel_pages']))
  {
    $level = $_GET['lavel_pages'];
    if($level == 'parent')
    {
      $query->query_vars['post_parent'] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      //get all the pages
      $pages = get_pages();

      //loop all the pages and store the parent id
      $parentIds = array();
      foreach($pages as $page)
      {
        $parentIds[$page->ID] = $page->post_parent;
      }

      //second time loop through all the pages this time call recursive function to get level
      foreach($pages as $page)
      {
        if($page->post_parent>0)
        {
          $pageLevels[$page->ID] = level_page_admin_get_level($parentIds, $page->ID, 0);
        }
      }

      //build array of only page ids on level
      $pageIds = array();
      foreach($pageLevels as $pageId => $pageLevel)
      {
        if($pageLevel==$level)
        {
          $pageIds[] = $pageId;
        }
      }

      if(!empty($pageIds))
      {
        //limit query to those page ids
        $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $pageIds;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. it's works great for me like I was looking.